# Change style only for one letter in a p

Tags: html, css

Assuming I have this HTML code:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Is there a way, with CSS only, without modifying the actual HTML, to change the style of the `w` in the `Hello world` text? (let's say, paint it green)

Comment: No. I think the best you'd be able to do is use a pseudo element like `::before` to inject the letter w, color it, and then position it on top the existing w. Hacky and fragile at best. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pLj6ra9f/

Comment: ya very fragile

Comment: @j08691 Hacky and fragile, but I think you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @j08691 better add background to the pseudo element : https://jsfiddle.net/pLj6ra9f/4/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that does improve the effect. I'm still not a fan enough for this method though to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `font-size` and the `font-family` are known, you can do this using gradient. Simply adjust the value so that only the `w` is colored

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  background: 
     linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, green 50%,green 67%,#000 67%);
  display: inline-block;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Comment: Can you perhaps explain how you managed to target the W? It seems kind of fragile, like it'll be dependent on font size, possibly resolution, the length of the string ... Not too responsive.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes exacty, as I said you need to know the font-family and the font-size .. it's not responsive and it cannot be generic ;) by the way, without changing the HTML, there is no generic solution, only hack and approximation ;)

Comment: Yes you said you need to know the font-family and font-size, but I have no idea how you managed to target the W exactly. Clearly it has to do with the percentages, but how do you come up with them and what do they mean?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I simply tried until I get the good ones :) % are the color stop, so you define when color end/begin ... change the values and you will see ;)

Answer (score 2):

No is not possible (unless it is the first letter), the workaround is using a `span` around the `w` and then style it

```css
p span {
  color: lightgreen
}

div::first-letter {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <span>w</span>orld</p>

<div>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: I gave a +1 because I did not know about the `first-letter` pseudo element. Pity there's no `nth-letter` equivalent since OP did explicitly call out "not changing the HTML" as a constraint so the solution for the other positions with span does not meet the criteria in the request.